# JMETER com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jmeter

I am sending the following query on JMeter. After sending it Job is created and it sends an email as it does in SQL server management studio but JMeter gives an error and the test doesn't pass even though the query is working.

> JMETER com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set

```
     Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'Tidal-Job-Scheduler@company.com'
                                           ,@from_address = 'someone@company.com'
                                           ,@blind_copy_recipients = 'someone@company.com'
                                           ,@subject = 'Start '
                                           ,@body = 'TEXT'
                                           ,@body_format = 'TEXT'
```

Comment: Please show **how** you are executing this in JMeter. It seems you are using something intended to execute queries (that is, something that produces a result set), while this statement does not produce a result set.

Comment: Can you please  more details so that we could better guide you..

Answer (score 0):

At the JDBC-request you can change the query type.

It may work when you choose for 'Callable Statement'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzHxL.png)